# S-DES Binary converted to ASCII?

Tags: encryption

I have been working with the following SDES Encryption templates and got the following as my ciphertext. I believe the ciphertext is correct because when I decrypted it I got my original plaintext.

[image]

If someone could inform me if the "**encoded binary value** is the ciphertext, and how do you convert this back to ASCII using the binary - ASCII table below?

[image]

Based on my results, I now have to answer the following questions, which I have answered in bold.

Plaintext binary value of e: **01100101**

**THE SUBKEYS WERE GENERATED USING THE KEY: 0101010110**

Key 1:**10011001**

Key 2: **01101010**

Encoded Binary Value: **11000001** (Is this regarded as the ciphertext?)

Finally convert, the encoded binary value back to ASCII: **?** (Could someone please explain how this is done?)

Answer (score 1):

> Encoded Binary Value: `11000001` (Is this regarded as the ciphertext?)

Yes. Or at least it is considered a block of ciphertext, as in, the output of a block cipher. A block cipher in itself is not a CPA secure cipher, as identical input messages (plaintext) will lead to identical output.

> Finally convert, the encoded binary value back to ASCII: ? (Could someone please explain how this is done?)

You look up `0110` on the top row listing the high order bits, and then lookup `0101` in the low order bits, so you'll find the lower case `e` again. Of course most computer languages have functions such as `CHR$` to do this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When it says convert the encoded binary value back to ASCII, is this the encoded binary value that I encrypted ("11000001") or do you just take the original plaintext for lower case "e"? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The latter. The ciphertext is binary, it doesn't represent a character, and as such it is not a good idea to convert it to text. ASCII actually only uses the 7 lower order bits, so `11000001` doesn't even represent an ASCII character. You would use hexadecimals or base 64 encoding if text is really required.